# "if a in b" statement used with different data types

Tags: python, logic

When I use the an in b statement with string, it works well. However, when my objects change to the type of list, it returns false even though the first list is in the second list. What's the logic behind this?

```
def f(a,b):
     if a in b:
        return True
     else: 
        return False

f('soifsdf','sh')
True
f([1, 2], [1, 2, 3])
False
```

I change another method [not in method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo6Ir.png), but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Objects can define `in` (via `__contains__`) as they choose. `list` only defines it for single elements. The are a number of reasons for this. One is consistency. Another is that it avoids multiple layers of ambiguity. For example, what if `b` contains an element equal to `a`? You also need to decide clearly whether you want subsequences, ordered subsets, or regular subsets including count or not.

Comment: "For example, what if b contains an element equal to a?" do you mean if they are equal like a=[ 1, 2,3], b =[1,2,3] this won't work?

Comment: @zoe I mean that a return value of True will mean different things for `[[1, 2, 3], 2, 3]` and `[1, 2, 3]`. Remember that lists can contain anything. Your expectation/suggestion would have made more sense if they only contained integers. In fact, that's how string containment is defined, because it makes sense in the general case